# How to use setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); in android?

Tags: android, textview, seekbar

I have downloaded the latest android SDK. I am trying to use a seekbar to change a textView's text size. But the problem is when I am writing these lines

```
bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
```

there is an error occurring. If I comment this line `//bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);`than the is running well but text size is not changing. I have tried too many ways but the app is not getting rid from that error. http://pastebin.com/2HTAXyvY this the link of my java file and http://pastebin.com/UcT3RBXL this is for error log.

Please help me to understand the error. Why it is happening?

Comment: In order for this to work in that context, you need to make sure that this actually implements an OnSeekBarChangeListener (look at John's answer). If it doesn't you can instantiate a new listener by doing bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){ // methods }

Comment: Show us your full code, we don't know what error your're getting so we cannot effectively help you.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2HTAXyvY here is the full code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UcT3RBXL here is the error log.

Comment: @TusharTushKhush see the edit to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your real problem is your `bar` is null. Check your XML file to make sure:

1. You are loading the correct XML file that contains your `bar`
2. You are using the correct ID to find `bar`
3. Make sure your IDs are spelled correctly

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong layout as fragment_main instead of activity_main.xml. As you can see here in your Activity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

You are using the activity_main layout. Whereas here in your fragment:

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
```

You use the `fragment_main.xml`

The simplest solution is to copy/paste all your `fragment_main.xml` elements inside the `activity_main.xml`. And remove these lines:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

which call your `Fragment` and display it inside your `FrameLayout` (in *activity_main.xml*)

Copied from Fllo